# Shopify Lazysizes.min.js file broken. Cant display images normally

Tags: javascript, image, shopify, lazy-loading

I am using Shopify Kalles theme. I tried to edit lazysizes.min.js in assets file and I did something wrong. My product images suddenly disapeared and cannot display and only show `lazyload` icon instead of thumbnails. I tried to revert js file but couldn't.

Please see [attached img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnSJ9.png). Following code is inside of (lazysizes.min.js)

```
window.lazySizesT4Config=window.lazySizesT4Config||{},window.lazySizesT4Config={init:!0,loadMode:!0,loadHidden:!1,hFac:.5,expFactor:2,ricTimeout:150,lazyClass:"lazyloadt4s",loadingClass:"lazyloadt4sing",loadedClass:"lazyloadt4sed",preloadClass:"lazypreloadt4s"},function(e,t){var n=function(){t(e.lazySizesT4),e.removeEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0)};t=t.bind(null,e,e.document),"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?t(require("lazySizesT4")):e.lazySizesT4?n():e.addEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0)}(window,function(e,t,n){"use strict";function a(e,n){if(!s[e]){var a=t.createElement(n?"link":"script"),i=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n?(a.rel="stylesheet",a.href=e):a.src=e,s[e]=!0,s[a.src||a.href]=!0,i.parentNode.insertBefore(a,i)}}var i,r,s={};t.addEventListener&&(r=/\(|\)|\s|'/,i=function(e,n){var a=t.createElement("img");a.onload=function(){a.onload=null,a.onerror=null,a=null,n()},a.onerror=a.onload,a.src=e,a&&a.complete&&a.onload&&a.onload()},addEventListener("lazybeforeunveil",function(e){var t,s,o;if(e.detail.instance==n&&!e.defaultPrevented){var l=e.target;if("none"==l.preload&&(l.preload="auto"),null!=l.getAttribute("data-autoplay"))if(l.getAttribute("data-expand")&&!l.autoplay)try{l.play()}catch(e){}else requestAnimationFrame(function(){l.setAttribute("data-expand","-10"),n.aC(l,n.cfg.lazyClass)});(t=l.getAttribute("data-link"))&&a(t,!0),(t=l.getAttribute("data-script"))&&a(t),(t=l.getAttribute("data-require"))&&(n.cfg.requireJs?n.cfg.requireJs([t]):a(t)),(s=l.getAttribute("data-bg"))&&(e.detail.firesLoad=!0,i(s,function(){l.style.backgroundImage="url("+(r.test(s)?JSON.stringify(s):s)+")",e.detail.firesLoad=!1,n.fire(l,"_lazyloaded",{},!0,!0)})),(o=l.getAttribute("data-poster"))&&(e.detail.firesLoad=!0,i(o,function(){l.poster=o,e.detail.firesLoad=!1,n.fire(l,"_lazyloaded",{},!0,!0)}))}},!1))}),function(e,t){var n=function(){t(e.lazySizesT4),e.removeEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0)};t=t.bind(null,e,e.document),"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?t(require("lazySizesT4")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["lazySizesT4"],t):e.lazySizesT4?n():e.addEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0)}(window,function(e,t,n){"use strict";addEventListener("lazybeforeunveil",function(e){var t=e.target,n=t.getAttribute("data-bgset"),a="1"!=new URLSearchParams(n).get("width");if(!(e.defaultPrevented||!n||n.indexOf("_1x1.")<0||a)){var i,r,s=t.getAttribute("data-ratio")||0,o=t.hasAttribute("data-hash"),l=n,d=(n="",(i=t.hasAttribute("data-widths")?JSON.parse(t.getAttribute("data-widths")):t.hasAttribute("data-wiis")?[180,360,540,720,900,1080]:[180,360,540,720,900,1080,1296,1512,1728,1950,2100,2260,2450,2700,3e3,3350,3750,4100]).length),u=a?l.split("_1x1."):l.split("width=1"),c=a?`${u[0]}x.`:`${u[0]}width=`,f=u[1];if(o&&s>0)for(r=0;r<d;r++)n+=c+"_"+i[r]+f+" "+i[r]+"w "+Math.round(i[r]*s)+"h, ";else for(r=0;r<d;r++)n+=c+"_"+i[r]+f+" "+i[r]+"w, ";n=n.slice(0,-2),t.setAttribute("data-bgset",n)}},!0)}),function(e,t){var n=function(){t(e.lazySizesT4),e.removeEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0)};t=t.bind(null,e,e.document),"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?t(require("lazySizesT4")):e.lazySizesT4?n():e.addEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0)}(window,function(e,t,n){"use strict";if(e.addEventListener){var a=n.cfg,i=/\s+/g,r=/\s*\|\s+|\s+\|\s*/g,s=/^(.+?)(?:\s+\[\s*(.+?)\s*\])(?:\s+\[\s*(.+?)\s*\])?$/,o=/^\s*\(*\s*type\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*\)*\s*$/,l=/\(|\)|'/,d={contain:1,cover:1},u=function(e,t){if(t){var n=t.match(o);n&&n[1]?e.setAttribute("type",n[1]):e.setAttribute("media",a.customMedia[t]||t)}},c=function(e){if(e.target._lazybgset){var t=e.target,a=t._lazybgset,i=t.currentSrc||t.src;if(i){var r=n.fire(a,"bgsetproxy",{src:i,useSrc:l.test(i)?JSON.stringify(i):i});r.defaultPrevented||(a.style.backgroundImage="url("+r.detail.useSrc+")")}t._lazybgsetLoading&&(n.fire(a,"_lazyloaded",{},!1,!0),delete t._lazybgsetLoading)}};addEventListener("lazybeforeunveil",function(e){var o,l,d;!e.defaultPrevented&&(o=e.target.getAttribute("data-bgset"))&&(d=e.target,(l=t.createElement("img")).alt="",l._lazybgsetLoading=!0,e.detail.firesLoad=!0,function(e,n,o){var l=t.createElement("picture"),d=n.getAttribute(a.sizesAttr),c=n.getAttribute("data-ratio"),f=n.getAttribute("data-optimumx"),y=n.getAttribute("data-sizes-scale");n._lazybgset&&n._lazybgset.parentNode==n&&n.removeChild(n._lazybgset),Object.defineProperty(o,"_lazybgset",{value:n,writable:!0}),Object.defineProperty(n,"_lazybgset",{value:l,writable:!0}),e=e.replace(i," ").split(r),l.style.display="none",o.className=a.lazyClass,1!=e.length||d||(d="auto"),e.forEach(function(e){var n,i=t.createElement("source");d&&"auto"!=d&&i.setAttribute("sizes",d),(n=e.match(s))?(i.setAttribute(a.srcsetAttr,n[1]),u(i,n[2]),u(i,n[3])):i.setAttribute(a.srcsetAttr,e),l.appendChild(i)}),d&&(o.setAttribute(a.sizesAttr,d),n.removeAttribute(a.sizesAttr),n.removeAttribute("sizes")),f&&o.setAttribute("data-optimumx",f),c&&o.setAttribute("data-ratio",c),y&&o.setAttribute("data-sizes-scale",y),l.appendChild(o),n.appendChild(l)}(o,d,l),setTimeout(function(){n.loader.unveil(l),n.rAF(function(){n.fire(l,"_lazyloaded",{},!0,!0),l.complete&&c({target:l})})}))}),t.addEventListener("load",c,!0),e.addEventListener("lazybeforesizes",function(e){if(e.detail.instance==n&&e.target._lazybgset&&e.detail.dataAttr){var t=e.target._lazybgset,a=t.dataset.parentFit||function(e){var t;return t=(getComputedStyle(e)||{getPropertyValue:function(){}}).getPropertyValue("background-size"),!d[t]&&d[e.style.backgroundSize]&&(t=e.style.backgroundSize),t}(t);d[a]&&(e.target._lazySizesT4ParentFit=a,n.rAF(function(){e.target.setAttribute("data-parent-fit",a),e.target._lazySizesT4ParentFit&&delete e.target._lazySizesT4ParentFit}))}},!0),t.documentElement.addEventListener("lazybeforesizes",function(e){var t,a;!e.defaultPrevented&&e.target._lazybgset&&e.detail.instance==n&&(e.detail.width=(t=e.target._lazybgset,a=n.gW(t,t.parentNode),(!t._lazySizesT4Width||a>t._lazySizesT4Width)&&(t._lazySizesT4Width=a),t._lazySizesT4Width))})}}),function(e,t){var n=function(){t(e.lazySizesT4),e.removeEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0)};t=t.bind(null,e,e.document),"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?t(require("lazySizesT4")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["lazySizesT4"],t):e.lazySizesT4?n():e.addEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0)}(window,function(e,t,n){"use strict";if(t.getElementsByClassName){var a,i,r,s,o,l,d=/\s*,+\s+/,u={complete:1,loaded:1},c={},f=/\s+/,y=/^(amd|css|module)\:(.+)/i,g=/(.+)\s+(\(\s*(.+)\s*\))/,v=/['"]/g,p=t.documentElement,z=t.getElementsByClassName("lazyconditionalinclude"),m=function(t,n){var a=t.ownerDocument.defaultView;return a.opener||(a=e),a.getComputedStyle(t,n||null)||{getPropertyValue:function(){},isNull:!0}},h=function(){var e,t,n=2,a=0,i=0,r=[],s=(t=function(){r.length&&(a=0)},function(){clearTimeout(e),e=setTimeout(t,999)});return{q:function(e){var t=null==e.getAttribute("data-lazyqueue");t&&(i++,n=3),a>n?r[t?"unshift":"push"](e):x(e)&&(a++,s())},d:function(){if(a&&a--,i>0&&(--i||(n=2)),!(a>n)){for(;r.length;)if(x(r.shift())){a++;break}s()}}}}(),b=(l=function(){for(var e=0,t=z.length;e<t;e++)!n.hC(z[e],a.lazyClass)&&C(z[e])&&n.aC(z[e],a.lazyClass)},function(e){clearTimeout(o),s=null,o=setTimeout(l,"resize"==e.type?31:0)});(a=n&&n.cfg).include||(a.include={}),(i=a.include).contentElement||(i.contentElement="html"),i.conditions||(i.conditions={}),i.map||(i.map={});var A=Shopify.routes.root;addEventListener("lazybeforeunveil",function(e){e.detail.instance==n&&!e.defaultPrevented&&e.target.getAttribute("data-rendert4s")&&(h.q(e.target),e.detail.firesLoad=!0)},!1),addEventListener("resize",b,!1),addEventListener("lazyrefreshincludes",b,!1)}function E(e){var t;(t=e.match(y))?this.urls[t[1]]=i.map[t[2]]||t[2]:this.urls.include=i.map[e]||e}function w(e){var t,n,r;return e=e.trim(),(n=(e=i.map[e]||e).match(g))?(r=n[1],t={condition:a.include.conditions[n[3]]||a.customMedia[n[3]]||n[2]||null,name:n[3]}):(r=e,t={condition:null,name:""}),t.urls={},(i.map[r]||r).split(f).forEach(E,t),!t.urls.include&&t.urls.amd&&(this.saved=!0,t.initial=this),t}function L(n,a){var o,l=!a.condition;return a.condition&&(s||(r||(r=t.querySelector(i.contentElement)),r?(o=(m(r,":after").getPropertyValue("content")||"none").replace(v,""),s={},o&&(s[o]=1),(o=(m(r,":before").getPropertyValue("content")||"none").replace(v,""))&&(s[o]=1)):s={}),s[a.name]?l=!0:e.matchMedia&&"string"==typeof a.condition?l=(matchMedia(a.condition)||{}).matches:"function"==typeof a.condition&&(l=a.condition(n,a))),l}function C(e){var t,n,a=e.lazyInclude;if(a&&a.candidates)for(t=0;t<a.candidates.length&&!L(e,n=a.candidates[t]);t++);return n&&n!=a.current||(n=null),n}function S(e,n,a){if(c[e])a&&(!0===c[e]?setTimeout(a):c[e].push(a));else{var i=t.createElement(!0===n?"script":"link"),r=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];if(n?(i.src=e,i.async=!1):(i.rel="stylesheet",i.href=e),c[e]=[],c[i.href]=c[e],a){var s,o=function(t){if("readystatechange"!=t.type||u[t.target.readyState]){var n=c[e];for(i.removeEventListener("load",o),i.removeEventListener("error",o),i.removeEventListener("readystatechange",o),i.removeEventListener("loadcssdefined",o),s&&clearInterval(s),c[e]=!0,c[i.href]=!0;n.length;)n.shift()()}};c[i.href][0]=a,n||(s=setInterval(function(){(function(e){for(var n=!1,a=t.styleSheets,i=e.href,r=0,s=a.length;r<s;r++)if(a[r].href==i){n=!0;break}return n})(i)&&o({})},60)),i.addEventListener("load",o),i.addEventListener("error",o),i.addEventListener("readystatechange",o),i.addEventListener("loadcssdefined",o)}r.parentNode.insertBefore(i,r)}}function T(e){e&&"function"==typeof e.lazytransform&&e.lazytransform(this)}function _(e){e&&"function"==typeof e.lazyunload&&e.lazyunload(this)}function N(e){e&&"function"==typeof e.lazyload&&e.lazyload(this)}function M(e,t){var a,i,r,s,o,l=e.lazyInclude.current||null,d={candidate:t,openArgs:["GET",t.urls.include,!0],sendData:null,xhrModifier:null,content:t.content&&t.content.content||t.content,oldCandidate:l};if(n.fire(e,"lazyincludeload",d).defaultPrevented)h.d();else{var u,c,f,y,g;if(o=function(){i&&r&&!s&&a()},a=function(){var a,s=i.status,o=i.content||i.responseText,d=!(null!=o||!l||!l.urls.include),u={candidate:t,content:o,text:i.responseText||i.content,response:i.response,xml:i.responseXML,isSuccess:!("status"in i)||(s>=200&&s<300||304===s),oldCandidate:l,insert:!0,resetHTML:d},c={target:e,details:u,detail:u};t.modules=r,l&&l.modules&&(l.modules.forEach(_,c),l.modules=null,u.resetHTML&&null==u.content&&t.initial&&t.initial.saved&&(u.content=t.initial.content)),r.forEach(T,c),a=n.fire(e,"lazyincludeloaded",u),u.insert&&u.isSuccess&&!a.defaultPrevented&&null!=u.content&&u.content!=e.innerHTML&&(e.innerHTML=u.content),h.d(),r.forEach(N,c),setTimeout(function(){n.fire(e,"lazyincluded",u)}),i=null,r=null},e.lazyInclude.current=t,e.setAttribute("data-currentrendert4s",t.name),t.urls.css&&(s=!0,u=t.urls.css,c=function(){s=!1,o()},f=(u=u.split("|,|")).length-1,u.forEach(function(e,t){S(e,!1,t==f?c:null)})),null==d.content&&t.urls.include?function(e,t){var n=new t4sXMLHttpRequest;n.addEventListener("readystatechange",function(){var e=this.DONE||4;this.readyState===e&&(t(n),n=null)},!1),n.open.apply(n,e.openArgs),n.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest"),e.xhrModifier&&e.xhrModifier(n,e.candidate),n.send(e.sendData)}(d,function(e){i=e,o()}):i=d,t.urls.amd||t.urls.module){var v=function(){r=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),o()};t.urls.amd?function(e,t){var a=(e=e.split("|,|")).length-1;n.cfg.requireJs?n.cfg.requireJs(e,t):e.forEach(function(e,n){S(e,n==a?t:null)})}(t.urls.amd,v):(y=t.urls.module,g=v,n.cfg.systemJs?n.cfg.systemJs(y,g):S(y,g))}else r=[];o()}}function x(e){var t;if(function(e){var t,a=e.getAttribute("data-set4url")||"";if(e.hasAttribute("data-qs-inl"))var r=A+"products/"+(e.getAttribute("data-rendert4s")||"")+"/?section_id=qs_inline";else r=(e.getAttribute("data-rendert4s")||"")+a;var s,o=e.lazyInclude;return o&&o.str==r&&!i.allowReload||(s={saved:!1,content:null},!(t=(o={str:r,candidates:(i.map[r]||r).split(d).map(w,s)}).candidates.length)||o.candidates[t-1].condition?(s.saved=!0,o.candidates.push({urls:{},condition:null,name:"initial",content:s})):s.saved&&1==o.candidates.length&&(s.saved=!1),o.initialContent=s,s.saved&&(s.content=e.innerHTML),e.lazyInclude=o,o.candidates.length>1?n.aC(e,"lazyconditionalinclude"):n.rC(e,"lazyconditionalinclude")),o}(e).candidates.length&&p.contains(e))return(t=C(e))&&M(e,t),!0}}),function(e,t){var n;e&&(n=function(){t(e.lazySizesT4),e.removeEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0)},t=t.bind(null,e,e.document),"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?t(require("lazySizesT4")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["lazySizesT4"],t):e.lazySizesT4?n():e.addEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0))}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:0,function(e,t,n){"use strict";var a=function(){function i(e){for(var t,a,i=0,r=e.length;i<r;i++)(a=(t=e[i]).target).getAttribute(t.attributeName)&&("source"==a.localName&&a.parentNode&&(a=a.parentNode.querySelector("img")),a&&y.test(a.className)&&function(e){n.rAF(function(){n.rC(e,c.loadedClass),c.unloadedClass&&n.rC(e,c.unloadedClass),n.aC(e,c.lazyClass),("none"==e.style.display||e.parentNode&&"none"==e.parentNode.style.display)&&setTimeout(function(){n.loader.unveil(e)},0)})}(a))}var r,s,o,l,d,u,c=n.cfg,f={"data-bgset":1,"data-include":1,"data-poster":1,"data-bg":1,"data-script":1},y="(\\s|^)("+c.loadedClass,g=t.documentElement;function v(){i(u),d=!(u=[])}c.unloadedClass&&(y+="|"+c.unloadedClass),y+="|"+c.loadingClass+")(\\s|$)",y=new RegExp(y),f[c.srcAttr]=1,f[c.srcsetAttr]=1,s=e.MutationObserver?(o=new MutationObserver(i),r=function(){l||(l=!0,o.observe(g,{subtree:!0,attributes:!0,attributeFilter:Object.keys(f)}))},function(){l&&(l=!1,o.disconnect())}):(g.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified",(u=[],function(e){l&&f[e.attrName]&&e.newValue&&(u.push({target:e.target,attributeName:e.attrName}),d||(setTimeout(v),d=!0))}),!0),r=function(){l=!0},function(){l=!1}),addEventListener("lazybeforeunveil",s,!0),addEventListener("lazybeforeunveil",r),addEventListener("lazybeforesizes",s,!0),addEventListener("lazybeforesizes",r),r(),removeEventListener("lazybeforeunveil",a)};addEventListener("lazybeforeunveil",a)}),function(e,t){var n;e&&(n=function(){t(e.lazySizesT4),e.removeEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0)},t=t.bind(null,e,e.document),"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?t(require("lazySizesT4")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["lazySizesT4"],t):e.lazySizesT4?n():e.addEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0))}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:0,function(e,t,n){"use strict";var a,i,r,s,o,l;e.addEventListener&&(a=/\s+(\d+)(w|h)\s+(\d+)(w|h)/,i=/parent-fit["']*\s*:\s*["']*(contain|cover|width)/,r=/parent-container["']*\s*:\s*["']*(.+?)(?=(\s|$|,|'|"|;))/,s=/^picture$/i,o=n.cfg,l={getParent:function(t,n){var a=t,i=t.parentNode;return n&&"prev"!=n||!i||!s.test(i.nodeName||"")||(i=i.parentNode),"self"!=n&&(a="prev"==n?t.previousElementSibling:n&&(i.closest||e.jQuery)&&(i.closest?i.closest(n):jQuery(i).closest(n)[0])||i),a},getFit:function(e){var t,n,a=getComputedStyle(e,null)||{},s=a.content||a.fontFamily,o={fit:e._lazySizesT4ParentFit||e.getAttribute("data-parent-fit")};return!o.fit&&s&&(t=s.match(i))&&(o.fit=t[1]),o.fit?(!(n=e._lazySizesT4ParentContainer||e.getAttribute("data-parent-container"))&&s&&(t=s.match(r))&&(n=t[1]),o.parent=l.getParent(e,n)):o.fit=a.objectFit,o},getImageRatio:function(t){for(var n,i,r,l,d,u,c=t.parentNode,f=c&&s.test(c.nodeName||"")?c.querySelectorAll("source, img"):[t],y=0;y<f.length;y++)if(n=(t=f[y]).getAttribute(o.srcsetAttr)||t.getAttribute("srcset")||t.getAttribute("data-pfsrcset")||t.getAttribute("data-risrcset")||"",i=t._lsMedia||t.getAttribute("media"),i=o.customMedia[t.getAttribute("data-media")||i]||i,n&&(!i||(e.matchMedia&&matchMedia(i)||{}).matches)){(r=parseFloat(t.getAttribute("data-aspectratio")))||(u=(l=n.match(a))?"w"==l[2]?(d=l[1],l[3]):(d=l[3],l[1]):(d=t.getAttribute("width"),t.getAttribute("height")),r=d/u);break}return r},calculateSize:function(e,t){var n,a,i,r=this.getFit(e),s=r.fit,o=r.parent;return"width"==s||("contain"==s||"cover"==s)&&(a=this.getImageRatio(e))?(o?t=o.clientWidth:o=e,i=t,"width"==s?i=t:(n=t/o.clientHeight)&&("cover"==s&&n<a||"contain"==s&&a<n)&&(i=t*(a/n)),i):t}},n.parentFit=l,t.addEventListener("lazybeforesizes",function(e){var t;e.defaultPrevented||e.detail.instance!=n||(t=e.target,e.detail.width=l.calculateSize(t,e.detail.width))}))}),function(e,t){var n=function(){t(e.lazySizesT4),e.removeEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0)};t=t.bind(null,e,e.document),"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?t(require("lazySizesT4")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["lazySizesT4"],t):e.lazySizesT4?n():e.addEventListener("lazyunveilread",n,!0)}(window,function(e,t,n){"use strict";var a,i,r=n.cfg,s={string:1,number:1},o=/^\-*\+*\d+\.*\d*$/,l=/^picture$/i,d=/\s*\{\s*width\s*\}\s*/i,u=/\s*\{\s*height\s*\}\s*/i,c=/\s*\{\s*([a-z0-9]+)\s*\}\s*/gi,f=/^\[.*\]|\{.*\}$/,y=/^(?:auto|\d+(px)?)$/,g=t.createElement("a"),v=t.createElement("img"),p="srcset"in v&&!("sizes"in v),z=!!e.HTMLPictureElement&&!p;function m(t,n,a){var r,s,d,u,y,g=e.getComputedStyle(t);if(a){for(u in y={},a)y[u]=a[u];a=y}else s=t.parentNode,a={isPicture:!(!s||!l.test(s.nodeName||""))};for(r in d=function(e,n){var r=t.getAttribute("data-"+e);if(!r){var s=g.getPropertyValue("--ls-"+e);s&&(r=s.trim())}if(r){if("true"==r)r=!0;else if("false"==r)r=!1;else if(o.test(r))r=parseFloat(r);else if("function"==typeof i[e])r=i[e](t,r);else if(f.test(r))try{r=JSON.parse(r)}catch(e){}a[e]=r}else e in i&&"function"!=typeof i[e]&&!a[e]?a[e]=i[e]:n&&"function"==typeof i[e]&&(a[e]=i[e](t,r))},i)d(r);return n.replace(c,function(e,t){t in a||d(t,!0)}),a}function h(e,n,r){var o=0,l=0,f=r;if(e){if("container"===n.ratio){for(o=f.scrollWidth,l=f.scrollHeight;!(o&&l||f===t);)o=(f=f.parentNode).scrollWidth,l=f.scrollHeight;o&&l&&(n.ratio=n.traditionalRatio?l/o:o/l)}var y,v,z;y=e,v=n,(z=[]).srcset=[],v.absUrl&&(g.setAttribute("href",y),y=g.href),y=((v.prefix||"")+y+(v.postfix||"")).replace(c,function(e,t){return s[typeof v[t]]?v[t]:e}),v.widths.forEach(function(e){var t=v.widthmap[e]||e,n=v.aspectratio||v.ratio,a=!v.aspectratio&&i.traditionalRatio,r={u:y.replace(d,t).replace(u,n?a?Math.round(e*n):Math.round(e/n):""),w:e};z.push(r),z.srcset.push(r.c=r.u+" "+e+"w")}),(e=z).isPicture=n.isPicture,p&&"IMG"==r.nodeName.toUpperCase()?r.removeAttribute(a.srcsetAttr):r.setAttribute(a.srcsetAttr,e.srcset.join(", ")),Object.defineProperty(r,"_lazyrias",{value:e,writable:!0})}}function b(e){var t=e.getAttribute(e.getAttribute("data-srcattr")||i.srcAttr)||e.getAttribute(a.srcsetAttr)||e.getAttribute(a.srcAttr)||e.getAttribute("data-pfsrcset")||"";return"1"!=new URLSearchParams(t).get("width")?t.replace("_1x1.","_{width}x."):t.replace("width=1","width={width}")}!function(){var e,t={prefix:"",postfix:"",srcAttr:"data-src",absUrl:!1,modifyOptions:function(){},widthmap:{},ratio:!1,traditionalRatio:!1,aspectratio:!1};for(e in(a=n&&n.cfg).supportsType||(a.supportsType=function(e){return!e}),a.rias||(a.rias={}),"widths"in(i=a.rias)||(i.widths=[],function(e){for(var t,n=0;!t||t<3e3;)(n+=5)>30&&(n+=1),t=36*n,e.push(t)}(i.widths)),t)e in i||(i[e]=t[e])}(),addEventListener("lazybeforesizes",function(e){var t,r,s,o,l,u,c,f,g,v,p,E,w;if(e.detail.instance==n&&(t=e.target,e.detail.dataAttr&&!e.defaultPrevented&&!i.disabled&&(g=t.getAttribute(a.sizesAttr)||t.getAttribute("sizes"))&&y.test(g))){if(s=function(e,t){var a=m(e,t);return i.modifyOptions.call(e,{target:e,details:a,detail:a}),n.fire(e,"lazyriasmodifyoptions",a),a}(t,r=b(t)),p=d.test(s.prefix)||d.test(s.postfix),s.isPicture&&(o=t.parentNode))for(u=0,c=(l=o.getElementsByTagName("source")).length;u<c;u++)(p||d.test(f=b(l[u])))&&(h(f,m(l[u],f,s),l[u]),E=!0);p||d.test(r)?(h(r,s,t),E=!0):E&&((w=[]).srcset=[],w.isPicture=!0,Object.defineProperty(t,"_lazyrias",{value:w,writable:!0})),E&&(z?t.removeAttribute(a.srcAttr):"auto"!=g&&(v={width:parseInt(g,10)},A({target:t,detail:v})))}},!0);var A=function(){var i=function(e,t){return e.w-t.w},s=function(e,t){var i;return!e._lazyrias&&n.pWS&&(i=n.pWS(e.getAttribute(a.srcsetAttr||""))).length&&(Object.defineProperty(e,"_lazyrias",{value:i,writable:!0}),t&&e.parentNode&&(i.isPicture="PICTURE"==e.parentNode.nodeName.toUpperCase())),e._lazyrias},o=function(t,a){var r,o,l,d,u,c;if((u=t._lazyrias).isPicture&&e.matchMedia)for(o=0,l=(r=t.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("source")).length;o<l;o++)if(s(r[o])&&!r[o].getAttribute("type")&&(!(d=r[o].getAttribute("media"))||(matchMedia(d)||{}).matches)){u=r[o]._lazyrias;break}return(!u.w||u.w<a)&&(u.w=a,u.d=function(t){var a=e.devicePixelRatio||1,i=n.getX&&n.getX(t);return Math.min(i||a,2.4,a)}(t),c=function(e){for(var t,n,a=e.length,i=e[a-1],r=0;r<a;r++)if((i=e[r]).d=i.w/e.w,i.d>=e.d){!i.cached&&(t=e[r-1])&&t.d>e.d-.13*Math.pow(e.d,2.2)&&(n=Math.pow(t.d-.6,1.6),t.cached&&(t.d+=.15*n),t.d+(i.d-e.d)*n>e.d&&(i=t));break}return i}(u.sort(i))),c},l=function(i){if(i.detail.instance==n){var d,u=i.target;p||!(e.respimage||e.picturefill||r.pf)?("_lazyrias"in u||i.detail.dataAttr&&s(u,!0))&&(d=o(u,i.detail.width))&&d.u&&u._lazyrias.cur!=d.u&&(u._lazyrias.cur=d.u,d.cached=!0,n.rAF(function(){u.setAttribute(a.srcAttr,d.u),u.setAttribute("src",d.u)})):t.removeEventListener("lazybeforesizes",l)}};return z?l=function(){}:addEventListener("lazybeforesizes",l),l}()}),function(e,t){var n=function(e,t,n){"use strict";var a,i;if(function(){var t,n={lazyClass:"lazyload",loadedClass:"lazyloaded",loadingClass:"lazyloading",preloadClass:"lazypreload",errorClass:"lazyerror",autosizesClass:"lazyautosizes",srcAttr:"data-src",srcsetAttr:"data-srcset",sizesAttr:"data-sizes",minSize:40,customMedia:{},init:!0,expFactor:1.5,hFac:.8,loadMode:2,loadHidden:!0,ricTimeout:0,throttleDelay:125};for(t in i=e.lazySizesT4Config||e.lazySizesT4Config||{},n)t in i||(i[t]=n[t])}(),!t||!t.getElementsByClassName)return{init:function(){},cfg:i,noSupport:!0};var r=t.documentElement,s=e.HTMLPictureElement,o=e.addEventListener.bind(e),l=e.setTimeout,d=e.requestAnimationFrame||l,u=e.requestIdleCallback,c=/^picture$/i,f=["load","error","lazyincluded","_lazyloaded"],y={},g=Array.prototype.forEach,v=function(e,t){return y[t]||(y[t]=new RegExp("(\\s|^)"+t+"(\\s|$)")),y[t].test(e.getAttribute("class")||"")&&y[t]},p=function(e,t){v(e,t)||e.setAttribute("class",(e.getAttribute("class")||"").trim()+" "+t)},z=function(e,t){var n;(n=v(e,t))&&e.setAttribute("class",(e.getAttribute("class")||"").replace(n," "))},m=function(e,t,n){var a=n?"addEventListener":"removeEventListener";n&&m(e,t),f.forEach(function(n){e[a](n,t)})},h=function(e,n,i,r,s){var o=t.createEvent("Event");return i||(i={}),i.instance=a,o.initEvent(n,!r,!s),o.detail=i,e.dispatchEvent(o),o},b=function(t,n){var a;!s&&(a=e.picturefill||i.pf)?(n&&n.src&&!t.getAttribute("srcset")&&t.setAttribute("srcset",n.src),a({reevaluate:!0,elements:[t]})):n&&n.src&&(t.src=n.src)},A=function(e,t){return(getComputedStyle(e,null)||{})[t]},E=function(e,t,n){for(n=n||e.offsetWidth;n<i.minSize&&t&&!e._lazySizesT4Width;)n=t.offsetWidth,t=t.parentNode;return n},w=(O=[],R=[],W=O,k=function(){var e=W;for(W=O.length?R:O,F=!0,q=!1;e.length;)e.shift()();F=!1},j=function(e,n){F&&!n?e.apply(this,arguments):(W.push(e),q||(q=!0,(t.hidden?l:d)(k)))},j._lsFlush=k,j),L=function(e,t){return t?function(){w(e)}:function(){var t=this,n=arguments;w(function(){e.apply(t,n)})}},C=function(e){var t,a,i=function(){t=null,e()},r=function(){var e=n.now()-a;e<99?l(r,99-e):(u||i)(i)};return function(){a=n.now(),t||(t=l(r,99))}},S=function(){var s,f,y,E,S,_,N,M,x,P,F,q,O,R,W,k,j,H,B,I=/^img$/i,$=/^iframe$/i,D="onscroll"in e&&!/(gle|ing)bot/.test(navigator.userAgent),J=0,U=0,V=-1,X=function(e){U--,(!e||U<0||!e.target)&&(U=0)},G=function(e){return null==q&&(q="hidden"==A(t.body,"visibility")),q||!("hidden"==A(e.parentNode,"visibility")&&"hidden"==A(e,"visibility"))},Q=function(e,n){var a,i=e,s=G(e);for(M-=n,F+=n,x-=n,P+=n;s&&(i=i.offsetParent)&&i!=t.body&&i!=r;)(s=(A(i,"opacity")||1)>0)&&"visible"!=A(i,"overflow")&&(a=i.getBoundingClientRect(),s=P>a.left&&x<a.right&&F>a.top-1&&M<a.bottom+1);return s},K=function(){var e,n,o,l,d,u,c,y,g,v,p,z,m=a.elements;if((E=i.loadMode)&&U<8&&(e=m.length)){for(n=0,V++;n<e;n++)if(m[n]&&!m[n]._lazyRace)if(!D||a.prematureUnveil&&a.prematureUnveil(m[n]))ie(m[n]);else if((y=m[n].getAttribute("data-expand"))&&(u=1*y)||(u=J),v||(v=!i.expand||i.expand<1?r.clientHeight>500&&r.clientWidth>500?500:370:i.expand,a._defEx=v,p=v*i.expFactor,z=i.hFac,q=null,J<p&&U<1&&V>2&&E>2&&!t.hidden?(J=p,V=0):J=E>1&&V>1&&U<6?v:0),g!==u&&(_=innerWidth+u*z,N=innerHeight+u,c=-1*u,g=u),o=m[n].getBoundingClientRect(),(F=o.bottom)>=c&&(M=o.top)<=N&&(P=o.right)>=c*z&&(x=o.left)<=_&&(F||P||x||M)&&(i.loadHidden||G(m[n]))&&(f&&U<3&&!y&&(E<3||V<4)||Q(m[n],u))){if(ie(m[n]),d=!0,U>9)break}else!d&&f&&!l&&U<4&&V<4&&E>2&&(s[0]||i.preloadAfterLoad)&&(s[0]||!y&&(F||P||x||M||"auto"!=m[n].getAttribute(i.sizesAttr)))&&(l=s[0]||m[n]);l&&!d&&ie(l)}},Y=(O=K,W=0,k=i.throttleDelay,j=i.ricTimeout,H=function(){R=!1,W=n.now(),O()},B=u&&j>49?function(){u(H,{timeout:j}),j!==i.ricTimeout&&(j=i.ricTimeout)}:L(function(){l(H)},!0),function(e){var t;(e=!0===e)&&(j=33),R||(R=!0,(t=k-(n.now()-W))<0&&(t=0),e||t<9?B():l(B,t))}),Z=function(e){var t=e.target;t._lazyCache?delete t._lazyCache:(X(e),p(t,i.loadedClass),z(t,i.loadingClass),m(t,te),h(t,"lazyloaded"))},ee=L(Z),te=function(e){ee({target:e.target})},ne=function(e){var t,n=e.getAttribute(i.srcsetAttr);(t=i.customMedia[e.getAttribute("data-media")||e.getAttribute("media")])&&e.setAttribute("media",t),n&&e.setAttribute("srcset",n)},ae=L(function(e,t,n,a,r){var s,o,d,u,f,v;(f=h(e,"lazybeforeunveil",t)).defaultPrevented||(a&&(n?p(e,i.autosizesClass):e.setAttribute("sizes",a)),o=e.getAttribute(i.srcsetAttr),s=e.getAttribute(i.srcAttr),r&&(d=e.parentNode,u=d&&c.test(d.nodeName||"")),v=t.firesLoad||"src"in e&&(o||s||u),f={target:e},p(e,i.loadingClass),v&&(clearTimeout(y),y=l(X,2500),m(e,te,!0)),u&&g.call(d.getElementsByTagName("source"),ne),o?e.setAttribute("srcset",o):s&&!u&&($.test(e.nodeName)?function(e,t){try{e.contentWindow.location.replace(t)}catch(n){e.src=t}}(e,s):e.src=s),r&&(o||u)&&b(e,{src:s})),e._lazyRace&&delete e._lazyRace,z(e,i.lazyClass),w(function(){var t=e.complete&&e.naturalWidth>1;v&&!t||(t&&p(e,"ls-is-cached"),Z(f),e._lazyCache=!0,l(function(){"_lazyCache"in e&&delete e._lazyCache},9)),"lazy"==e.loading&&U--},!0)}),ie=function(e){if(!e._lazyRace){var t,n=I.test(e.nodeName),a=n&&(e.getAttribute(i.sizesAttr)||e.getAttribute("sizes")),r="auto"==a;(!r&&f||!n||!e.getAttribute("src")&&!e.srcset||e.complete||v(e,i.errorClass)||!v(e,i.lazyClass))&&(t=h(e,"lazyunveilread").detail,r&&T.updateElem(e,!0,e.offsetWidth),e._lazyRace=!0,U++,ae(e,t,r,a,n))}},re=C(function(){i.loadMode=3,Y()}),se=function(){3==i.loadMode&&(i.loadMode=2),re()},oe=function(){f||(n.now()-S<999?l(oe,999):(f=!0,i.loadMode=3,Y(),o("scroll",se,!0)))};return{_:function(){S=n.now(),a.elements=t.getElementsByClassName(i.lazyClass),s=t.getElementsByClassName(i.lazyClass+" "+i.preloadClass),o("scroll",Y,!0),o("resize",Y,!0),o("pageshow",function(e){if(e.persisted){var n=t.querySelectorAll("."+i.loadingClass);n.length&&n.forEach&&d(function(){n.forEach(function(e){e.complete&&ie(e)})})}}),e.MutationObserver?new MutationObserver(Y).observe(r,{childList:!0,subtree:!0,attributes:!0}):(r.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted",Y,!0),r.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified",Y,!0),setInterval(Y,999)),o("hashchange",Y,!0),["focus","mouseover","click","load","transitionend","animationend"].forEach(function(e){t.addEventListener(e,Y,!0)}),/d$|^c/.test(t.readyState)?oe():(o("load",oe),t.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",Y),l(oe,2e4)),a.elements.length?(K(),w._lsFlush()):Y()},checkElems:Y,unveil:ie,_aLSL:se}}(),T=(M=L(function(e,t,n,a){var i,r,s;if(a*=parseFloat(e.getAttribute("data-sizes-scale")||1),e._lazySizesT4Width=a,a+="px",e.setAttribute("sizes",a),c.test(t.nodeName||""))for(i=t.getElementsByTagName("source"),r=0,s=i.length;r<s;r++)i[r].setAttribute("sizes",a);n.detail.dataAttr||b(e,n.detail)}),x=function(e,t,n){var a,i=e.parentNode;i&&(n=E(e,i,n),(a=h(e,"lazybeforesizes",{width:n,dataAttr:!!t})).defaultPrevented||(n=a.detail.width)&&n!==e._lazySizesT4Width&&M(e,i,a,n))},P=C(function(){var e,t=N.length;if(t)for(e=0;e<t;e++)x(N[e])}),{_:function(){N=t.getElementsByClassName(i.autosizesClass),o("resize",P)},checkElems:P,updateElem:x}),_=function(){!_.i&&t.getElementsByClassName&&(_.i=!0,T._(),S._())};var N,M,x,P;var F,q,O,R,W,k,j;return l(function(){i.init&&_()}),a={cfg:i,autoSizer:T,loader:S,init:_,uP:b,aC:p,rC:z,hC:v,fire:h,gW:E,rAF:w}}(e,e.document,Date);e.lazySizesT4=n,"object"==typeof module&&module.exports&&(module.exports=n)}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:{}),document.addEventListener("lazyincludeloaded",function(e){if(e.detail.content&&e.detail.content.indexOf("[t4splitlz]")>-1){var t=e.detail.content.split("[t4splitlz]")[1];e.detail.content=t}}),document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("lazysizet4s:loaded")),document.addEventListener("lazyloaded",function(e){let t=e.target.parentNode;t&&t.classList.contains("t4s-bg-11")&&t.classList.add("t4s-child-lazyloaded")});
```

Expecting solution to display imgs normally..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.